# Migrating from Maven Ant Task to Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks

Tags: java, ant, maven-3, maven-ant-tasks

Last week our project stopped working because maven-ant-task seems to be calling maven central with `http` instead of `https` and now it's enforced, so it returns a `501`.

We saw that Apache released a new library [Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/index.html), so we're trying to migrate.

This is our old file, used to call our in-house jaxb library to generate java classes. The dependency is `dome-jaxb` and we were resolving it with `maven-ant-tasks`.

```
<project name="Main" basedir="../../" xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">

   <!-- ==================== Execution Classpath =========================== -->
   <artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset" useScope="runtime">
      <dependency groupId="com.dome" artifactId="dome-jaxb" version="LATEST"/>
   </artifact:dependencies>

   <path id="Execute.classpath">
      <fileset refid="dependency.fileset"/>
      <pathelement path="target/classes"/>
   </path>

   <!-- ==================== Type Target ===================================== -->
   <target name="Types" description="Generate type">
      <java classname="dome.util.xml.converter.GenerateClassFromXMLConfig" fork="yes">
         <sysproperty key="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
         <arg value="${basedir}"/>
         <arg value="${xmlConfig}"/>
         <arg value="${moduleId}"/>
         <classpath refid="Execute.classpath"/>
      </java>
   </target>
</project>
```

I downloaded the project, generated the uber jar (after that I found out that you can also download it [here](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-ant-tasks/1.2.1/maven-resolver-ant-tasks-1.2.1-uber.jar)), and added it to my ant/lib (where the `maven-ant-task.jar` is located).

The new configuration file I managed to put together is this one:

```
<project name="Main" basedir="../../" xmlns:resolver="antlib:org.apache.maven.resolver.ant">

   <!-- ==================== Execution Classpath =========================== -->
   <taskdef uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.resolver.ant" resource="org/apache/maven/resolver/ant/antlib.xml">
      <classpath>
         <fileset dir="target" includes="maven-resolver-ant-tasks-*uber.jar"/>
      </classpath>
   </taskdef>

   <path id="Execute.classpath">
      <pathelement path="target/classes"/>
   </path>

   <resolver:resolve>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency
            groupId="com.dome"
            artifactId="dome-jaxb"
            version="LATEST"
            scope="runtime"
         />
      </dependencies>      
      <path refid="Execute.classpath" classpath="runtime"/>
   </resolver:resolve>

   <!-- ==================== Type Target ===================================== -->
   <target name="Types" description="Generate type">
      <java classname="dome.util.xml.converter.GenerateClassFromXMLConfig" fork="yes">
         <sysproperty key="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
         <arg value="${basedir}"/>
         <arg value="${xmlConfig}"/>
         <arg value="${moduleId}"/>
         <classpath refid="Execute.classpath"/>
      </java>
   </target>

</project>
```

This seems to work, but it looks like it's not using my `settings.xml` which is located in `~/.m2/` (the default location, which reading the documentation should be used), because we have a nexus repository with our local libraries, but it seems that it's only checking the maven central repository since the error is:

`Could not find artifact com.dome:dome:jar:4.23.0 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)`

I've seen in the documentation that you can manually set your `settings.xml` location, but there's no example or indication as *where* to put that configuration, so I couldn't get it working.

If anyone has any idea / suggestion, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it seems that defining the repository manually it works, but if it's defined in my settings.xml, shouldn't it be unnecessary to do this?

Comment: In Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks the <mvn> task is missing. What did you do to replace it in your migrated code?

Answer (score 1):

I have observed the same and I think it is a bug in `maven-resolver org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts()`.  I'm able to avoid the issue as long as there is a maven-metadata.xml for each artifact I need to resolve.  So, my workaround is to:

1. Copy our deployment repository to `~/.m2/repository` to set the baseline
2. Use `mvn -DupdateReleaseInfo=true` for any local install
3. Use `mvn dependency:go-offline` and `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=...` to resolve any other dependencies before running Ant

Comment: Please report bugs with us.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely affected by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOLVER-66. I haven't looked at it, but will happily accept patches.

Comment: Yes, I believe it is the same as that Jira issue.  I will see if I can find more detail.

Comment: I have commented on Jira and created https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver-ant-tasks/pull/3.  Thanks!